# How to detect EC2 instance has been idle

Tags: unix, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am looking for idea how to approach this problem, basically measuring EC2 instance activity.

Is there a way I can know that via AWS? If not, how can I measure activity on e.g. Ubuntu instance. Taking into account that I will have some processes running and looking into their activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are defining "instance activity" but you can monitor your [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instance with [Amazon CloudWatch](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) and then query on the *CPUUtilization* metric to get information about how much CPU your instance is using (see [Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud Dimensions and Metrics](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/CW_Support_For_AWS.html#ec2-metricscollected) for details).

Comment: Not bad there is an API and all, I will look into this but it seems that what I was looking for.

Comment: You can also store your own custom metrics in CloudWatch.  So, you could have something on your instance that was storing a more meaningful measure of activity and then use the API to query for that.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to measure by 2 metrics and compare, Network traffic and CPU utilization

Ref: [https://www.trendmicro.com/cloudoneconformity/knowledge-base/aws/EC2/idle-instance.html#:~:text=Using%20AWS%20Console-,01%20Sign%20in%20to%20the%20AWS%20Management%20Console.,to%20identify%20the%20right%20resource](https://www.trendmicro.com/cloudoneconformity/knowledge-base/aws/EC2/idle-instance.html#:%7E:text=Using%20AWS%20Console-,01%20Sign%20in%20to%20the%20AWS%20Management%20Console.,to%20identify%20the%20right%20resource)).